# Elasticsearch, how to convert ip long to string, to get ip subnets aggs

Tags: elasticsearch

there is a field named ip, which mapped to ip type, now i want to aggs as /24 subnets, i use script "doc['ip'].value & 0xffffff00" to get long value of ip, how to next to convert it to ip string???

```
{
  "_source": [
    "host",
    "ip"
  ],
  "aggs": {
    "ip_subnet": {
      "terms": {
        "script": "doc['ip'].value & 0xffffff00"
      }
    }
  },
  "size": 0
}
```

I didn't found any result from elastic website, I wonder know if there is another way to receive the subnets aggs?

Thank you very much, and forgive my pool english ;)

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I finished by define a longToIp similar script... Maybe there is another good solution...

```
"aggs": {
    "ip_subnet": {
      "terms": {
        "script": "ip=doc['ip'].value & 0xffffff00;octet3 = (int) ((ip >> 24) % 256);octet2 = (int) ((ip >> 16) % 256);octet1 = (int) ((ip >> 8) % 256);octet0 = (int) ((ip) % 256);ipstr=octet3 + '.' + octet2 + '.' + octet1 + '.' + octet0;return ipstr+\"/24\";"
      }
    }
  },
```